# How a child can access it's parent's property only using CSS? is it possible?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

How each `span` element gets it's parent's `title` property in css? is it possible ? is it possible if I use `scss` or `less` or something?

```
<div>
<div title="hello"><span> </span></div>
<div title="dear"><span> </span></div>
<div title="world"><span> </span></div>
</div>
```

so after applying `css` styling, it's result should be equivalent to this

```
<div>
<div title="hello"><span>hello</span></div>
<div title="dear"><span>dear</span></div>
<div title="world"><span>world</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not likely. But very simple in JS

Comment: Please tell more briefly what you want?

Comment: I know it's possible in js but I just need it in css. so it's not possible. is it possible if i use `scss` or `less` ?

Comment: @ibnelaiq he likely wants something like `div > span::before { content: div[title] }` which does not exist

Comment: @mplungjan yes that's what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible that child can access it's parent properties in pure CSS.
There are some ways to access parent via child in javascript.
instead there is a a method of getting this `:has`.Documentation Here. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has
The following selector matches only `<a>` elements that directly contain an `<img>` child:

```
a:has(> img)
```

*But there is **no** method to access the parent via child.*

Like this you can access your parent like

```
div:has(> span){
//Do Here what you want./
}
```

> As of 2019, this is still not supported by any browser.